# Cloud VPN tunnel in "Established" state but can't reach private IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipsec

So, I've just set a Google Cloud VPN to merge my local network with my cloud network.

In Google Cloud Console, it says that the connection between Cloud VPN and my Peer VPN Gateway is established and I see a green icon. It is a IKEv2 connection.

But I can't reach any of the private IPs on my Google Cloud.

I have activated VPN and VPC logs and I can see how my requests get to Google but I don't know what the problem would be or how to debug.

My GCloud private network is: 10.10.0.0/16
My local network is: 10.116.32.0/24

And I can see Log entries on my VPC of me trying to reach 10.10.0.2 (which is a virtual machine running NGINX and SSH) from the browser and SSH (I have the firewall rules too) but I can't connect. (I can using the public IP though)

An example:

```
 {
 insertId: "xxxxxxxxx"  

jsonPayload: {
  bytes_sent: "0"   

connection: {
   dest_ip: "10.116.32.120"    
   dest_port: 50988    
   protocol: 6    
   src_ip: "10.10.0.2"    
   src_port: 80    
  }
  end_time: "2019-05-21T07:39:20.422232110Z"   
  packets_sent: "2"   
  reporter: "SRC"   

src_instance: {
   project_id: "xxxxxxx"    
   region: "xxxxxxx"    
   vm_name: "instance-1"    
   zone: "xxxxxx"    
  }

src_vpc: {
   project_id: "xxxxxxxx"    
   subnetwork_name: "main-vpc-subnet"    
   vpc_name: "main-cluster-vpc"    
  }
  start_time: "2019-05-21T07:39:20.422094550Z"   
 }
 logName: "projects/xxxxxx/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fvpc_flows"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-05-21T07:39:25.609210362Z"  

resource: {

labels: {
   location: "xxxxxxxx"    
   project_id: "xxxxxxxxxx"    
   subnetwork_id: "xxxxxxxxxx"    
   subnetwork_name: "main-vpc-subnet"    
  }
  type: "gce_subnetwork"   
 }
 timestamp: "2019-05-21T07:39:25.609210362Z"  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a route configured back to your local network?

Comment: Changing the route type from policy based to route based it works, and in route based is 0.0.0.0/0 by default

Comment: Where did you configure `0.0.0.0/0`. This sends all traffic back thru your network. You probably do not want that.